# I have a text and i have to store it in Array then get all punctuations out and the printed text should be in lowCase. I am new in Java

Tags: java, arrays

For exemple : "Today is a big day! I asked Questions about Java" should be like "today is a big day i asked questions about java"

Comment: Please, when asking a question only put the actual question in the title and try to phrase it as a question. That makes it easier to understand.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a homework or work dump. You have to at least try to solve it first and show the fruits of your efforts with your question. We're not here to do your work for you.

Comment: Thanks for answering @youtubefreak of course i tried something i just didnt know where to post my code because of thats my first time writing here :)

Answer (score -1):

public static char[] normalisieren(char[] text) throws IOException {

```
    BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new
```

FileReader("c:/readIt.txt"));

```
    String texte;

     ArrayList<String> reText = new ArrayList<String>();

        while((texte = keyboard.readLine()) != null){
            reText.add(texte);
        }

        String[] stringArr = reText.toArray(new String[0]);
        for(int i = 0; i < stringArr.length; i++){
      //  System.out.println(stringArr[i]);
        String str = stringArr[i].toLowerCase();
        System.out.println(str);
        }
        return text;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    normalisieren(null);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Google the items below and apply them on your code.

- Java String lowercase
- Java String remove punctuations

Comment: 1. Don't answer such poor questions until they're improved. 2. Don't post poor answers either.

Comment: Thank you both i am sorry for writing "poor questions" thats just i am new here and didnt undertand about how to formulate questions here. But thank you for answering  @HovercraftFullOfEels:)

Comment: @sitm don't apologize, improve your question.